# Pyspark Join on condition A, if not then Join on B, etc

Tags: python, apache-spark, join, pyspark

Table 1 has 10 rows that need to fill in missing data.
Table 2 has 100 rows of potential matches.
Both tables have columns x,y,z.
I want to join one row from Table 2 to each row in Table 1.

Logic:
First see if x,y,z all match.  this is the best case.  if so, join on this row.
If not x,y,z match, then try just x,y.
Finally, just x.

There can be many matches in Table 2, where it could have 1 xyz match, and 1 xy match.  In this case it should only match the xyz.

I was thinking something like this:

```
final = when(table1.join((table2, table1["x"] == table2["x"]) & (table2, table1["y"] == table2["y"]), "left").otherwise((table2, table1["x"] == table2["x"]))
```

I keep getting multiple rows per line, which will break the system.  I need to tell it that if xyz match is found, stop right there and don't check for xy match.

Answer (score 0):

use `if` and `else` to check. That is, when the comparison will take place. Let's say he checked x and placed it. After you ask if there is something in this cell, if yes, then he should stop if not, then he will continue the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If the data volume is not too much, you can do 3 joins (left->left->inner) with decreasing strictness for comparison (x,y,z -> x,y -> x) combination. The matching rows will become input for consecutive joins and union them together in the end.

However, the most efficient way here will be to write a custom zipPartition logic on RDDs and compare the keys as per your logic. This will just iterate the left and right data-frames once and will be best for huge data-frames. This approach will also help you restrict the output to first match (in case x == x will match millions of row, you can code to just pick the first matching row)